# I need to create hypothesis test on series of question

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, hypothesis-test

I need to perform hypothesis test on the following questions:

- Is saving money (finances) gender dependant?
- Is there any differences in money saving (finances) between people from city or village?
- Do Women have a Healthier Lifestyle than Men?
- Are Village People Healthier than City People?

I have a set of data similar to the following

```
Healthy eating Finances Gender Village - town
4.0             3.0     female   village
3.0             3.0     female   city
3.0             2.0     female   city
3.0             2.0     female   city
4.0             4.0      male    village
```

I am trying to identify what method of hypothesis testing is required to provide solution to the above questions.

I have tried Chi square of independence for the first question whether finance is dependent on gender but not sure if Chi square test of independence is the right one to be used and below is the right way to infer the hypothesis

```
chi_sq_Stat, p_value, deg_freedom, exp_freq = stats.chi2_contingency(dfSurvey["Finances"])
print('Chi-square statistic %3.5f P value %1.6f Degrees of freedom %d' %(chi_sq_Stat, p_value,deg_freedom))
```

I need to perform the required statistical tests to validate/reject the Hypothesis in above set of questions.

Comment: .....Is that home work ?

Comment: yes and I am not well versed with the stats part as to which test will suit the above scenarios